# Boundary Value problem - multiple argument

Tags: python, scipy, pde

I am developing a model for the 1-D geometry product which is exposed to different conditions on the top and bottom surface as you can see in the code. Unfortunately, for the boundary condition, it is always giving error as bc takes multiple argument which should take single argument.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import solve_bvp

# Constants
Ly = 0.0015  # Total thickness of the system (meters)
T = 40  # Total simulation time (seconds)
Ny = 51  # Number of spatial grid points
Nt = 50000  # Number of time steps
velocity_x = 0.2  # line speed in m/s

# Thermal properties of different layers
layer1_thickness = 0.001  # Thickness of layer 1 (meters)
layer1_k = 0.15  # Thermal conductivity of layer 1 (W/m-K)
layer2_thickness = 0.5e-3  # Thickness of layer 2 (meters)
layer2_k = 0.16  # Thermal conductivity of layer 2 (W/m-K)

rho_1 = 1250  # density of layer 1 (kg/m³)
rho_2 = 1520  # density of layer 2 (kg/m³)
cp_1 = 1350  # specific heat capacity of layer 1 (J/kg-K)
cp_2 = 1460  # specific heat capacity of layer 2 (J/kg-K)

T_roller = 150  # Temperature of hot roller (°C)
h_roller = 500  # Convective heat transfer coefficient (W/m2-K)
T_cooling_roller = 22  # Temperature of cooling temperature(°C)

# Ambient temperature and convection properties
T_ambient = 25  # Ambient temperature (°C)
h_air = 12  # Convective heat transfer coefficient of air (W/m²-K)
radiation_length = 1.280  # radiation length in m
radiation_width = 2.300  # radiation width in m
radiation_power = 138e3  # W
radiative_flux = 50e3  # W/m2
absorption = 45  # in %
performance = 95  # in %
emissivity = 0.91  # emissivity values range from 0.90 to 0.93

# if radiative flux is given
# Net_radiative_intensity = radiative_flux*(absorption/100)*(performance/100);
# if radiation power is given
Net_radiative_intensity = (radiation_power / (radiation_length * radiation_width)) * (absorption / 100) * (
            performance / 100) * emissivity

# Discretization in space
ny1 = np.ceil(layer2_thickness / Ly * Ny).astype(int)
ny2 = Ny - ny1
y1 = np.linspace(0, layer2_thickness, ny1)
y2 = np.linspace(layer2_thickness, Ly, ny2)
y = np.concatenate((y1, y2[1:]))

# Initialize temperature matrix
initial_temperature1 = 25
initial_temperature2 = 25

dia_roller = 0.8  # diameter of hot roller (m)
dia_cooling_roller = 0.57  # diameter of cooling roller(m)
contact_angle = 180  # contact angle/wrap angle for hot_roller in °
contact_angle_cool1 = 120  # contact angle/wrap angle for cooling_roller1 in °
contact_angle_cool2 = 220  # contact angle/wrap angle for cooling_roller2 in °
contact_angle_cool3 = 190  # contact angle/wrap angle for cooling_roller3 in °

y_1 = np.pi * dia_roller * contact_angle / 360  # in contact with hot roller
y_2 = 0.3  # after hot roller
y_3 = radiation_length  # in contact with IR
y_4 = 0.3  # after IR

t1 = y_1 / velocity_x
t2 = y_2 / velocity_x
t3 = y_3 / velocity_x
t4 = y_4 / velocity_x

nt1 = np.ceil(t1 / (t1 + t2 + t3 + t4) * Nt).astype(int)
nt2 = np.ceil(t2 / (t1 + t2 + t3 + t4) * Nt).astype(int)
nt3 = np.ceil(t3 / (t1 + t2 + t3 + t4) * Nt).astype(int)
nt4 = Nt - (nt1 + nt2 + nt3)

t11 = np.linspace(0, t1, nt1)
t12 = np.linspace(t1, t1 + t2, nt2)
t13 = np.linspace(t1 + t2, t1 + t2 + t3, nt3)
t14 = np.linspace(t1 + t2 + t3, t1 + t2 + t3 + t4, nt4)


# pdepe settings
def pdefun(y, t, u, dudy,phase):
    if y <= layer2_thickness:
        c = rho_2 * cp_2
        f = layer2_k * dudy
        s = 0
    else:
        c = rho_1 * cp_1
        f = layer1_k * dudy
        s = Net_radiative_intensity  # source term for IR radiation
    return c, f, s


# defining the initial conditions for pde
def icfun(yq,phase):
    if phase == 1:
        return np.where(yq <= layer2_thickness, initial_temperature1, initial_temperature2)
    elif phase == 2:
        return np.interp(yq, y, u1[-1, :])
    elif phase == 3:
        return np.interp(yq, y, u2[-1, :])
    else:
        return np.interp(yq, y, u3[-1, :])
    
def get_bc_values(phase):
    if phase == 1:
        pl = -h_air * (sol.y[0, 0] - T_ambient)
        ql = 1
        pr = h_roller * (sol.y[0, -1] - T_roller)
        qr = 1
    elif phase == 2:
        pl = -h_air * (sol.y[1, 0] - T_ambient)
        ql = 1
        pr = h_air * (sol.y[1, -1] - T_ambient)
        qr = 1
    elif phase == 3:
        pl = -h_air * (sol.y[2, 0] - T_ambient)
        ql = 1
        pr = -Net_radiative_intensity
        qr = 1
    else:
        pl = -h_air * (sol.y[3, 0] - T_ambient)
        ql = 1
        pr = h_air * (sol.y[3, -1] - T_ambient)
        qr = 1
    return pl, ql, pr, qr

"""
# defining the boundary conditions for pde
def bcfun(yl, ul, yr, ur, t,phase):  # right is for top and left is for bottom
    if phase == 1:
        pl = -h_air * (ul - T_ambient)
        ql = 1
        pr = h_roller * (ur - T_roller)
        qr = 1
    elif phase == 2:
        pl = -h_air * (ul - T_ambient)
        ql = 1
        pr = h_air * (ur - T_ambient)
        qr = 1
    elif phase == 3:
        pl = -h_air * (ul - T_ambient)
        ql = 1
        pr = -Net_radiative_intensity
        qr = 1
    else:
        pl = -h_air * (ul - T_ambient)
        ql = 1
        pr = h_air * (ur - T_ambient)
        qr = 1
    return pl, ql, pr, qr
"""
def bc(ya, yb, phase):
    return get_bc_values(phase)

# Concatenate time arrays
t_all = np.concatenate((t11, t12, t13, t14))


# Solve the system using solve_bvp
sol = solve_bvp(pdefun, icfun, y, t_all, bc=bc)
# sol = solve_bvp(pdefun, icfun, y, t_all, bc=bcfun)


# Extract solution
u1 = sol.sol(t11)[0]
u2 = sol.sol(t12)[0]
u3 = sol.sol(t13)[0]
u4 = sol.sol(t14)[0]
```

here i am solving transient heat transfer.I have tried different approach but every time same error is coming up

and the error is

```
sol = solve_bvp(pdefun, icfun, y, t_all, bc=bc)

 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ TypeError: solve_bvp() got multiple values for argument 'bc'
```

Could someone please help or tell how to avoid the multiple argument for bc?

i have a working model in matlab and i am trying to develop the same in python and as the problem type is boundary value problem, i have used solve_bvp module but as one guy mentioned in the comment that there should be only bc not ic, then is there any other method to develop this code maybe using daetools or somehting else?

```
function pde()
% Constants
Ly = 0.0015;        % Total thickness of the system (meters)
T = 40;             % Total simulation time (seconds)
Ny = 51;            % Number of spatial grid points
Nt = 50000;         % Number of time steps
velocity_x = 0.2;   %line speed in m/s


% Thermal properties of different layers
layer1_thickness = 0.001;  % Thickness of layer 1 (meters)
layer1_k = 0.15;            % Thermal conductivity of layer 1 (W/m-K)
layer2_thickness = 0.5e-3;  % Thickness of layer 2 (meters)
layer2_k = 0.16;            % Thermal conductivity of layer 2 (W/m-K)

rho_1 = 1250;           %density of layer 1 (kg/m³)
rho_2 = 1520;           %density of layer 2 (kg/m³)
cp_1 = 1350;            %specific heat capacity of layer 1 (J/kg-K)
cp_2 = 1460;            %specific heat capacity of layer 2 (J/kg-K)

T_roller = 150;         %Temperature of hot roller (°C)
h_roller = 500;         %Convective heat transfer coefficient (W/m2-K)
T_cooling_roller = 22;  %Temperature of cooling temperature(°C)
% layer3_thickness = 0.002;  % Thickness of layer 3 (meters)
% layer3_k = 0.3;            % Thermal conductivity of layer 3 (W/m-K)

% Ambient temperature and convection properties
T_ambient = 25;                     % Ambient temperature (°C)
h_air = 12;                         % Convective heat transfer coefficient of air (W/m²-K)
radiation_length = 1.280;           %radiation length in m
radiation_width = 2.300;            %radiation width in m
radiation_power = 138e3;            %W
radiative_flux = 50e3;              %W/m2
absorption = 45;                    % in %
performance = 95;                   % in %
emissivity = 0.91;                  %emissivity values range from 0.90 to 0.93

%if radiative flux is given
%Net_radiative_intensity = radiative_flux*(absorption/100)*(performance/100);
%if radiation power is given
Net_radiative_intensity = (radiation_power/(radiation_length*radiation_width))*(absorption/100)*(performance/100)*emissivity;

%Discretization in space
ny1 = ceil(layer2_thickness/Ly*Ny);
ny2 = Ny-ny1;
y1 = linspace(0,layer2_thickness,ny1);
y2 = linspace(layer2_thickness,Ly,ny2);
y = [y1,y2(2:end)];

% Initialize temperature matrix
initial_temperature1 = 25;
initial_temperature2 = 25;

dia_roller = 0.8;                   %diameter of hot roller (m)
dia_cooling_roller = 0.57;           %diameter of cooling roller(m)
contact_angle = 180;                %contact angle/wrap angle for hot_roller in °
contact_angle_cool1 = 120;          %contact angle/wrap angle for cooling_roller1 in °
contact_angle_cool2 = 220;          %contact angle/wrap angle for cooling_roller2 in °
contact_angle_cool3 = 190;          %contact angle/wrap angle for cooling_roller3 in °

y_1 = pi*dia_roller*contact_angle/360;              %in contact with hot roller
y_2 = 0.3;                                          %after hot roller
y_3 = radiation_length;                             %in contact with IR
y_4 = 0.3;                                          %after IR

t1 = y_1/velocity_x;
t2 = y_2/velocity_x;
t3 = y_3/velocity_x;
t4 = y_4/velocity_x;

nt1 = ceil(t1/(t1+t2+t3+t4)*Nt);
nt2 = ceil(t2/(t1+t2+t3+t4)*Nt);
nt3 = ceil(t3/(t1+t2+t3+t4)*Nt);
nt4 = Nt-(nt1+nt2+nt3);

t11 = linspace(0,t1,nt1);
t12 = linspace(t1,t1+t2,nt2);
t13 = linspace(t1+t2,t1+t2+t3,nt3);
t14 = linspace(t1+t2+t3,t1+t2+t3+t4,nt4);


%pdepe settings
m = 0;  %for 1-D cartesian coordinates with no symmetry
phase = 1;
sol = pdepe(m, @pdefun, @icfun, @bcfun, y, t11);
%sol = pdepe(m,@pdefun,@icfun,@bcfun,y,t11);
u1 = sol(:,:,1);
phase = 2;
sol = pdepe(m, @pdefun, @icfun, @bcfun, y, t12);
%sol = pdepe(m,@pdefun,@icfun,@bcfun,y,t12);
u2 = sol(:,:,1);
phase= 3;
sol = pdepe(m, @pdefun, @icfun, @bcfun, y, t13);
%sol = pdepe(m,@pdefun,@icfun,@bcfun,y,t13);
u3 = sol(:,:,1);
phase=4;
sol = pdepe(m, @pdefun, @icfun, @bcfun, y, t14);
%sol = pdepe(m,@pdefun,@icfun,@bcfun,y,t14);
u4 = sol(:,:,1);

plot([t11,t12,t13,t14],[[u1(:,1);u2(:,1);u3(:,1);u4(:,1)],[u1(:,25);u2(:,25);u3(:,25);u4(:,25)],[u1(:,50);u2(:,50);u3(:,50);u4(:,50)]])
grid on

%assigning the coefficients for pde 
function [c f s] = pdefun(y,t,u,dudy)
  if y <= layer2_thickness
    c = rho_2*cp_2;
    f = layer2_k*dudy;
    s = 0;
  else
    c = rho_1*cp_1;
    f = layer1_k*dudy;
    s = Net_radiative_intensity;%source term for IR radiaiton
  end
end

%defining the initial conditions for pde
function u = icfun(yq)
  if phase==1
    if yq <= layer2_thickness
      u = initial_temperature1;
    else
      u = initial_temperature2;
    end
  elseif phase==2
    u = interp1(y,u1(end,:),yq);
  elseif phase==3
      u = interp1(y,u2(end,:),yq);
  else
      u = interp1(y,u3(end,:),yq);
  end
end

%defining the boundary conditions for pde
    function [pl ql pr qr] = bcfun(yl,ul,yr,ur,t)%right is for top and left is for bottom
  if phase==1
    pl = -h_air*(ul-T_ambient);
    ql = 1;
    pr = h_roller*(ur-T_roller);
    qr = 1;
  elseif phase==2
    pl = -h_air*(ul-T_ambient);
    ql = 1;
    pr = h_air*(ur-T_ambient);
    qr = 1;
  elseif phase==3
    pl = -h_air*(ul-T_ambient);
    ql = 1;
    pr = -Net_radiative_intensity;
    %pr = h_air*(ur-T_ambient)
    qr = 1;
  else
    pl = -h_air*(ul-T_ambient);
    ql = 1;
    pr = h_air*(ur-T_ambient);
    qr = 1;

  end
end
end
```

Comment: Your question was originally about the boundary condition error, but now you added on and asked about how to do this properly in Python. Stick to one question per post. If my answer fixed your original question then accept it by clicking the check next to it and create a new post with your new question. Keep in mind that your current code is not good for a stack Overflow post. Code should be as short as possible while yours is both long and has tons of unexplained logic and variables that people will not want to do. I advise slimming down your code significantly for your next post.

Comment: thankyou @jared for your reply. I will keep in mind what you have said.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_bvp.html), the second argument of `solve_bvp` is for the boundary condition function. So, you give it `icfun` as the second argument and then you also give it a keyword argument for `bc`. You've doubled up on what `bc` is so `solve_bvp` is "confused".

I'm not sure what `icfun` is actually supposed to be used for nor why you're passing it to `solve_bvp`. Also note that you have other syntax errors in your code. You should review the documentation and verify how the ODE function (why do you have it called PDE?) should be defined and used (`y` will be a numpy array, not a scalar) as well as how the `bc` function should be defined and used.

Comment: thankyou for your reply. I got your point.
y will be a scalar as it is 1-D geometry so it is the thickness
actually i have a model in matlab which is working and i try to develop the same in python and as the state of the problem is there, it is boundary value problem
i am trying to solve the laplace heat equation for transient state

Comment: For `solve_bvp`, `y` is a vector where each entry is the value of whatever your solution is at that grid/mesh point. You have `y` as a vector since you defined it as a concatenation of vectors earlier in your code.